# make project multilingual with Zend/Translator

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-translate

Good evening,

I want to add zend/translate to my project to show my webside in several languages. But there doesn't work anything. Here are the steps I done already:

In the module.config.php I looked if the translator is initialized:

```
...

'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',

...

'translator' => array(
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),

...
```

In the Module.php in the Bootstrap I set the DefaultTranslator:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

    \Locale::setDefault('de_DE');
    \Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator(
            $e->getApplication()
                    ->getServiceManager()
                    ->get('translator')
    );
}
```

But when I reload my webside there is a error like this:

```
 Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator() must be an instance of Zend\Validator\Translator\TranslatorInterface, instance of Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\pimp\module\Application\Module.php on line 28 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\pimp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator.php on line 472
```

I think there is something I've forgotten..

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a odd part in Zend i18n that Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator is not compatible with other components. The Mvc Translator binds the Translator to the other parts. The `Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator` extends the "normal" translator and then it implements the translator interface requested by the Zend\Validator component.

So, create the Mvc Translator by using the MVC translator factory. Replace `Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory` with `Zend\Mvc\Service\TranslatorServiceFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

this is simple tutorial 
http://samminds.com/2012/09/zend-framework-2-translate-i18n-locale/ 
http://www.poedit.net/ 
but i have

```
   ,'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'translate',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern' => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

in module.config.php and a php file that all keys exist on it for example

```
<?php 

    /*
     * General keys
     */
    $this->translate('projectname');
    $this->translate('login');
    $this->translate('logout');
    $this->translate('pages');
    $this->translate('contents');
    $this->translate('ourposition');            
    $this->translate('search_pleace');  
    $this->translate('contactform');
    $this->translate('pleaseuploadresume');

?>
```

in poedit i only set path of this file. (help to better management) and on Catalog properties-> sources keywords translate should be exist ( and of course be better one)  . any where i want show message . i write

```
echo $this->translate('key');
```